# access a website behind openvpn client

Tags: routing, openvpn, apache2

I have an openvpn server (10.x.x.1) and a client (10.x.x.2) with a php webapp on apache.
I can access this webapp with my PC (with openvpn client installed, 10.x.x.3) over the vpn network with his ip address 10.x.x.2.

My problem is that I have to give access to this application to certain people and I want to give them public access without having to install a vpn client.

So I would like to give them a public url on the openvpn server, example : https://public-ip-of-my-vpn-server/webapp and that this URL route to the client (10.x.x.2) or something like this but I don't know how to go about it.

Do you have a solution for me?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Configure a *reverse proxy* on your VPN server (e.g. Apache with `ProxyPass`, or Nginx, or similar). This is the same kind of situation as using a reverse proxy or load balancer frontend with a separate web server; the fact that the network between proxy and backend happens to be a VPN tunnel doesn't change much at all.

Comment: Thank you so much !! I had started trying with ProxyPass but I was not convinced that it could work. After your message I persevered on it and now it works!